# Why should a phrase be called as "think tank" and not as as "thinking tank"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, verbs

[Source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=thinking%20tank&oq=thinking%20tank&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2767j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I wonder why should we form the phrase using combination of two nouns-**think** and **tank**. Should it not be grammatical to use a noun and a verb for forming a noun phrase like **thinking tank**. What's the idea?

Comment: Using two nouns to form a compound word is perfectly fine. There are a lot of words with two nouns like tree-house, flowerpot etc. It would supplement your question if you can add the source where you read that compound words should be a combination of a verb and a noun.

Comment: We nominalize verbs all the time.   *This new video game is fun. Would you like to have a **go**?*  Or *I can't get this door to budge. -- OK, let me have a **try**.*  or *It's so noisy here. I need a place to have a good **think**.*

Comment: *think* is not really a noun, though.

Comment: "Why don't you go have **a think** about that." "I need to have **a think** about that" are standard BrE sentences.

Comment: @Peter - Fair enough!  I should have said that I don't really think *think* is a noun **in this context** - a "think tank" is not "a tank for a think" in the way that a "fish tank" is "a tank for a fish".

Comment: @stangdon I think **think** is indeed a noun here, not a verb. Probably the difference is that with some nouns the meaning is different than with others.

Answer (score 1):

A **"think tank"** is a compound noun that means *"a place where one thinks"* and a **"thinking tank"** would probably mean some kind of [**tank**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank) or [**tank**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_tank) that can think.

Take for a instance a **bomb shelter** and a **bombing shelter**.

1. A **bomb shelter** is any kind of a civil defense structure designed to provide protection against the effects of a bomb.
2. A **bombing shelter** is theoretically a shelter that can initiate bombing procedures and bomb somewhere. Some kind of AI infested fallout shelter.

Comment: A *dive bomber* is probably a bomber that can dive. (It can also initiate kills.)  So this doesn't seem to support by analogy your brief analysis of the OP's choices.

Comment: A **talk box** is a device that musicians use, a **talking box** is a radio or a TV.

Comment: But by this line of reasoning, a "moving truck" would be a truck that moved, a "drying rack" would be a rack that dried, and a "receiving line" would be a line that received.

Comment: @ruakh not really, since "moving" and "drying" are both gerunds in those examples, so they're working as nouns, not verbs. Having trouble deciding if "dive" in "dive bomber" is more verby, though.

Comment: @cjl750: Sorry, I don't see your point. If you're contending that "thinking" can't be a gerund in "thinking tank", then I'd love to hear your argument for that. How is "thinking tank" different from, say, "thinking cap"?

Comment: @ruakh I'll admit, upon further reflection, I'd agree that it's not really any different. Unfortunately, I don't think that helps the OP. If there is a rule to describe why it's "think tank" and not "thinking tank," I can't come up with it. May just come down to having to learn the phrase.

Comment: Taking "thinking" as a participle, a "thinking tank" would indeed be a tank that thinks. Taking "thinking" as a gerund, a "thinking tank" could be a tank _used_ somehow for thinking, such as by climbing inside and thinking a while. Along that line, a [leaching tank](https://grabcad.com/library/leaching-tank-1) is one used for running a certain chemical process ("leaching", as a gerund), which occurs inside the tank.

Comment: @BenKovitz How can we know if it's a participle or a gerund?

Comment: @SovereignSun You can't! At least not without context—and sometimes not even then. The subject of the verb "leach" is most commonly most commonly the liquid that dissolves a substance on a solid, but sometimes the solid is the subject, and it would be reasonable to say that the tank the holds both the liquid and the solid "does" the leaching. Sometimes the ambiguity matters. E.g. is a "shaming act" a ritual by which a community pronounces shame on someone (gerund) or an act that shames the person who did it (participle)? Fortunately it's seldom a problem in practice.

Comment: @SovereignSun Wait! Duh! There is a way: by rhythm and intonation (not shown in writing). A "**sham**ing act" has the gerund, and a "shaming **act**" has the participle.

Comment: @BenKovitz Jee, tat's that simple, hee. I wonder if it really matters in a context since I guess the meaning can be understood precisely from the context.

Comment: @SovereignSun I think that when naming variables in computer programs or in very terse places like that, it's sometimes been a problem for me. For example, is `matching-code` code that you call to match something (gerund) or a code describing how well something matches (gerund) or a code that already matches something (participle)? But yeah, context usually clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

The term **think tank** is *irreverent.* That is, it's a little bit playful.

[Think tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_tank) are usually prestigious, dignified organizations where leading experts in their fields, with the highest credentials, think very deeply about important matters of government policy, reaching very reliable conclusions only after considering the most thorough and carefully researched data available. Or at least that's how they want to be perceived. Notice that their official names are usually very dignified. Here are some well-known American think tanks: the Brookings Institution, the Heritage Foundation ("heritage" connotes old, traditional, valuable, dignified), the Cato Institute (named [indirectly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cato%27s_Letters) after [Cato the Younger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cato_the_Younger), an ancient Roman defender of republican ideals against dictatorship), and the Center for Economic Policy and Research. These titles sound very, very serious.

So *of course* people are going to have to invent a playful, teasing name for them.

First of all, the word **tank** is quite undignified as a name for these organizations. It vaguely suggests that the high-powered, credentialed experts are thrown together into a cistern or a storage tank. A similar-sounding term is [**drunk tank**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drunk_tank), a jail cell where people who have been drunk and disorderly used to be held until they sober up—another playful, undignified phrase, suggesting "a tank in which drunks are stored".

Using **think**, normally a verb, as an attributive noun, sounds informal and jovial. It playfully suggests that "think" is the substance held or produced in the "tank". "Thought" would be a more conventional way to say what is meant by "think" in "think tank", but for that reason, it wouldn't be playful.

[image]

<sup>Source: [Composite Tanks and Vessels Pvt. Ltd.](https://www.indiamart.com/compositetanksvessels/frp-storage-tank.html)</sup>

Pour your "[eggheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egghead)" in here, wait a while, and some "think" should come out the spout.

(The [OED's](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200809) oldest citation for "think tank" in this sense is from 1958—the era when "egghead" was a popular slang term for intellectual.)

Comment: Does the downvoter work for Composite Tanks and Vessels Pvt. Ltd.?

Comment: Why did they call a **think tank** after all?

Comment: @SovereignSun I think it's just creative, playful use of language, sort of like poetry. "Think tank" is also a playful, undignified way to refer to the brain. That's a slightly older usage, predating its use for a policy institute. It may have influenced people to call policy institutes "think tanks", since the people who work in such places are called "brains" by metonymy, and hence by another metonymy the the whole institute is a "brain"—but I have no evidence that that's how it happened. …

Comment: @SovereignSun … A friend of mine calls the brain "the upstairs fuck-bucket". I'm pretty sure she made that up. Referring to the brain as a mundane sort of container for liquids ("tank", "bucket") seems to be a natural metaphor if you want to refer to the brain, or intellect, disparagingly. Another playfully disparaging synonym for brain is "noodle". That one, I've never understood. People just make these things up, drawing upon pre-existing connotations and associations. Even grammar has connotations, like the way "think tank" is more jovial or playful than "thought tank" or "thinking tank".

Comment: Yeh, this stuff I know, we do absolutely the same things in Russian. I never got to understand my friend who calls his brain the place where hen are kept - can't remember the Englush word.

Comment: @SovereignSun A henhouse? Chicken coop?

Comment: Yeh, henhouse - курятник. That is really strange but it looks like he's got hen instead of cocrouches there.

Comment: @SovereignSun Ha! That's excellent: calling the brain a [курятник](http://landscape-project.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/kuryatnik-svoimi-rukami-6.jpg) wonderfully suggests a distinctive combination of chaos and order—and babbling. That suggests to me another factor that might play a role in "think tank": tanks are usually big, heavy, and stable—just like policy institutes.

Comment: Did I spell cocroaches correctly? So you think it wise to call the brain *a henhouse*? If you mention the big industrial tanks then yes, they are gigantic and broad

Comment: @SovereignSun Did you mean "cockroaches"? As for calling the brain a henhouse, I think that's got to be much wiser than calling it a think tank or a fuck-bucket. ;) Seriously, it seems like quite a good [metaphor](http://osnovam.ru/sites/default/files/IMG/Osamadmin/kuriatnik_svoimi_rukami.jpg) to me, but it might be lost on people who've never seen a henhouse. I've never heard it in English, but that's OK.